# How to use arrays and loops correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm doing a bit of music chord theory coding, and ran into problems populating and modifying arrays in loops.

Ultimately I want to compute the chords from just a list of notes.

I want the capitalization of the letters in the `Akkorde` array (which is logged to the console secondly) to match the capitalization of the letters in the `Notenname` array (which is logged to the console firstly).

```js
const Noten = [
 [[0, "A", null]],
 [[1, "A", "#"], [1, "B", "b"]],
 [[2, "B", null]],
 [[3, "C", null]],
 [[4, "C", "#"], [4, "D", "b"]],
 [[5, "D", null]],
 [[6, "D", "#"], [6, "E", "b"]],
 [[7, "E", null]],
 [[8, "F", null]],
 [[9, "F", "#"], [9, "G", "b"]],
 [[10, "G", null]],
 [[11, "G", "#"], [11, "A", "b"]]
];

const Akkorde = [];

var Auswahl = 0;
var Schritt = 3;

for (let JedeNote = 0; JedeNote < 2 * Noten.length; JedeNote++) {
  let Grundton = Noten[Auswahl];

  Grundton.forEach(Notenname => {
    Notenname[1] =
      Schritt === 3 ?
      (Notenname[1] = Notenname[1].toLowerCase()) :
      (Notenname[1] = Notenname[1].toUpperCase());
    console.log(Notenname);
  });

  let Akkord = [Grundton];
  Akkorde.push(Akkord);

  Auswahl += Schritt;
  Auswahl = Auswahl >= 12 ? (Auswahl -= 12) : Auswahl;

  Schritt = Schritt === 3 ? 4 : 3;
}

console.log(Akkorde);
```

I expect the letter capitalization to be alternating: "a", "C", "e", "G", ... etc.

The actual result is a wrong capitalization: "A", "c", "E", "g", ... and so on.

Please try running the code, so you can understand the problem and answer me what I have to change!

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Oscar, if the current algorithm gives you the opposite result to what you wish to achieve, invert the logic that gives the actual result. Just change `Schritt === 3` to `Schritt !== 3` that way you can obtain the notes in the corrent capitalization.

Comment: It's not that simple. The first console output is totally fine - the problem is with the second one. It should match the data from the first output.

Comment: Exactly, the output is different because the comparison should be inverted. You have to change it to lowercase when `Schritt === 4` or when `Schritt !== 3`

Comment: Uh. I know that. But have you inspected the second console output? It's not correct even if you switch the comparison to `!== 3`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Oscar sorry for doubting you, after revising your code i did these corrections:

```
const Noten = [
    [[0, "A", null]],
    [[1, "A", "#"], [1, "B", "b"]],
    [[2, "B", null]],
    [[3, "C", null]],
    [[4, "C", "#"], [4, "D", "b"]],
    [[5, "D", null]],
    [[6, "D", "#"], [6, "E", "b"]],
    [[7, "E", null]],
    [[8, "F", null]],
    [[9, "F", "#"], [9, "G", "b"]],
    [[10, "G", null]],
    [[11, "G", "#"], [11, "A", "b"]]
];

const Akkorde = [];

var Auswahl = 0;
var Schritt = 3;

for (let JedeNote = 0; JedeNote < 2 * Noten.length; JedeNote++) {
  let Grundton = Noten[Auswahl];

  //Map the values from Grundton to a variable Akkord
  let Akkord = Grundton.map(Notenname => {
    //Copy the value of the element into a new variable
    const Akkordname = [...Notenname];
      //Only make the note lowercase if Schritt === 3
      if(Schritt === 3) {
        Akkordname[1] = Akkordname[1].toLowerCase();
      }
    console.log("Notenname", JSON.stringify(Akkordname));
    return Akkordname;
  });

  Akkorde.push(Akkord);

  Auswahl += Schritt;
  Auswahl = Auswahl >= 12 ? (Auswahl - 12) : Auswahl;

  Schritt = Schritt === 3 ? 4 : 3;
}

console.log("Akkorde", JSON.stringify(Akkorde));
```

Hope this helps.